Protagonist smuggles swords through an airport in a case filled with clay
I saw this movie when I was very young, and remember bits and pieces that are largely unsearchable. It has sentimental value to me, and I'd love to watch it again as an adult.

The main guy in the movie was a killer or some kind.
There were swords in the movie. Asian-looking.
At one point the main protagonist smuggled swords or guns or something though an airport in a case, which was filled with clay.

I know it's not much to go on, but the clay thing is specific enough to uniquely identify it, I'm sure. 

When were you young? Was the movie in English? Hollywood? More information please.

If the "clay thing" was specific enough to identify it, you would have done so. Unless you remember what was smuggled, you have "Guy smuggles something in clay", which is not specific.

Googling around for this at work is awkward ...

Possibly Crying Freeman from 1995? The synopsis here mentions the airport/suitcase/clay scene.

Oh my, you figured it out! Thank you so much. :)
